# ¿Qué sentido tienen las variables de entorno en producción?

Tags: php, deployment, symfony4

Ayer fué la primera vez que hice deploy en un servidor propio y con Symfony 4. Viendo la [documentación oficial](https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html) que toca el tema *deployment*, cito:

> Most Symfony applications read their configuration from environment
>   variables. While developing locally, you'll usually store these in a
>   .env file. But on production, instead of creating this file, you
>   should set real environment variables.

Ahora, desde que leí en varios lugares que esta sería la forma correcta de trabajar, me han surgido varias dudas al respecto:

- ¿Qué sentido tienen las variables de entorno en producción? ¿Por qué no simplemente tener las variables en un archivo como Wordpress, Django o el sentido común?
- ¿¿¿Por qué motivo querría tener las credenciales de la base de datos de un proyecto web en una variable global del sistema operativo???
- Siendo globales y accesibles por todos en el SO, si tengo más de un proyecto en el sistema que usan la misma variable de entorno (como es el caso de `APP_ENV` para Symfony), entonces cambiar esa variable afectaría a todos los proyectos en el sistema! ¿Cuál sería la gracia?

Si alguien pudiera arrojarme un poco de luz sobre el tema, se lo agradecería muchísimo